# Github View Counter

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api, github-for-windows, github-copilot

I want to know how many people viewed my github account. Is there a plugin used for this? it would be much more functional if it was a IP counter. so I want to know if my github account is checked in job applications that I send cv to. I'm waiting for your help.